# how to make matlab detect incompatible type assignments?

Tags: matlab, type-conversion, variable-assignment

hi have a major problem in matlab. I have a function and it sometimes returns control ascii characters. How do i check for the presence of these control ascii ?.

my code looks like this

```
d = out.autoc
```

d sometimes receives control ascii characters instead of a actual double value. Does someone know how to catch such incompatible assignments ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work but you may want to double check the ASCII codes to exclude.

```
%here I load Ctrl-C
s = sprintf('%s', 3);
code = bin2dec(dec2bin(s,8));
if code < 32 
  fprintf('ignore');
else
  fprintf('do somsething');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that the value of `d` is double, and not a string. You can check it this way:

```
if ~isnumeric(d) || ~isdouble(d)
    fprintf('d is not of class double\n');
end
```

But if you want to assign the value of `out.autoc` to `d` only if `out.autoc` is double, you can do this:

```
if isnumeric(out.autoc) && isequal(class(out.autoc), 'double')
    d = out.autoc;
else
    fprintf('out.autoc is not of class double, no assignment made.\n');
end
```